# Finding an application within the system files

Tags: linux, bash, macos, file

I want the script to be able to find an application within the whole file system as the application is not always installed in the /Applications folder. I want to find it to remove it. Currently I have a script that looks in the users application folder and the general applications folder which is shared by all accounts. However, the application is sometimes stored in a different place.

currently the script checks if the process (the application) is running, if not then delete the application from the specified folder.

Is there any way to do a general sweep ?

```
#!/bin/bash

process="$4"

#check if abc is running
if pgrep $process >/dev/null 2>&1
  then
     echo $process is running

     exit 1
  else

    echo $process is not running - remove all versions 


    #Remove ALL versions of Skype for Business.app 
rm -rf $HOME/Applications/"Skype for Business.app"
rm -rf /Applications/"Skype for Business.app"

#Trigger the skype install policy
sudo jamf policy -event installSkype
echo "triggering install policy for Skype"


fi
```

Comment: Did you look at https://superuser.com/questions/226566/how-do-i-find-a-file-by-filename-in-mac-osx-terminal

Comment: @Fazlin I just took a look at it. Im finding it difficult to incorporate the find function into the script. could you possibly help?

Comment: Does something like this help? `mdfind -onlyin / kMDItemKind==Application | grep -i skype` I avoid Microsoft products, so I don't know exactly how Skype shows up, that's why I did a general case-insensitive `grep`.

Comment: @MarkSetchell perfect. that works in finding it, but I'm not sure how to incorporate into the script, so it can then delete all the instances of 'skype' once they've been found.

Comment: I don't like writing shell scripts that do `rm -rf ANYTHING` so I'll leave it to someone else to pick up from there.